# Is this enough info to solve this time dilation problem

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebra-precalculus

There are two clocks.  One is a regular clock measuring regular time $\tau$.  The other is a clock measuring time $t$ which also advances clockwise, but does not advance uniformly--it accelerates w.r.t. $\tau$ from 12 to 6 o'clock, and decelerates from 6 to 12, such that the two clocks always tell the same time at 12 and 6.  It is given that the alternating acceleration and deceleration of $t$ w.r.t. $\tau$ is uniform--$\frac{d^2t}{d\tau^2}=K$ where $K$ is a constant.  Is this enough info to determine the "dilation" $\frac{dt}{d\tau}$?  If not, what other info is needed?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a straightforward application of integration... Not sure what this has to do with "time dilation" since there's nothing about traveling at relativistic speeds.

You have: $\frac{d^2t}{d\tau^2}=K$ and you wish to find $\frac{dt}{d\tau}$. Consider the situation piecewise and integrate: from 12 to 6, $\int{\frac{d^2t}{d\tau^2}d\tau}=\frac{dt}{d\tau}=K\tau+C$. You know that at t=12, $\tau=12$. For convenience, set 12 o'clock = 0. So $\frac{dt}{d\tau}=K\tau$. Be careful: there is a discontinuity at 6 o'clock (as measured by $\tau$), and K changes to -K so your $\frac{dt}{d\tau}=-K\tau$ from 6 to 12.

It is not possible for both clocks to read the same time at 6 under the given conditions since $\frac{dt}{d\tau}=K\tau$ implies t will be ahead of $\tau$ for the entire interval from 12 to 6.

Comment: $\frac{dt}{d\tau}=K\tau$ would imply $t>\tau$ for the entire interval only if $\frac{dt}{d\tau} \geq 1$ at the starting position 12 o'clock.  However, no such condition is imposed in this problem.  Indeed, it should be readily apparent from the information given that $\frac{dt}{d\tau} <1$ at 12 and $\frac{dt}{d\tau}>1$ at 6.